# Problem with Replace in Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, grep, replace

I'm using regex to match all non-quoted property names in my json files. Eclipse has no problem finding the desired matches, but when I want to replace the matched strings with `"$2"`, I get this error: `Match string has changed in file filename.json. Match skipped`

Here's the regex I'm using:

```
((\w+)\s*(?!['"])(?=:))
```

Any idea on how to work around this issue?

Comment: Just a wild thought: I think it is failing on the capturing group inside another capturing group. Maybe $2 doesn't exist, it only has $1 and 3 sub groups in that. No idea how you'd access those though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a known bug: [replace don't work when using a regex with a lookahead](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=109481)

Comment: 1 hour banging my head... and it was a bug!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a problem with the tool rather than the regex, but I'm not familiar with Eclipse so I can't be more specific.  Could it be expecting `\2` instead of `$2`?

Assuming the property names match `\w+`, that regex should work fine, although the negative lookahead is redundant.  If the next character is a colon--`(?=:)`--then of course it isn't an apostrophe or quotation mark--`(?!['"])`.

Comment: Eclipse does uses $1, $2, not \1, \2. Thanks for improving the regex, BTW.